# Migrating from one cluster to another

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr

I have a source emr cluster with hive metastore as a external mysql ( emr version 3.1 ).
We are planning to upgrade a cluster to 5.11.1.

Does anyone know how to migrate hive and hdfs from one cluster to another with a remote mysql metastore?

Answer (score 0):

None of your data should be on HDFS persistently. Copy any important files to S3.

HIve provides metastore upgrade scripts for all versions.

Use `schematool` command available under `/usr/lib/hive/bin` to perform an upgrade migration.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool